# Why can apparently any monad stack generally derive MonadIO?

Tags: haskell, io, monad-transformers

I'm confused that the compiler doesn't complain about the code below (the code compiles):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO)
import Control.Monad.Except   (ExceptT)

main = undefined

newtype Foo e m a = Foo { unFoo :: ExceptT e m a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
```

It would immediately make sense to me again, if I had to add `MonadIO m` as constraint somewhere, e.g.

```
deriving instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (Foo e m a)
```

and indeed, if I try

```
deriving instance MonadIO (Foo e m a),
```

the compiler complains.

I also noticed that I can only use `liftIO` when I add the constraint `MonadIO m` there, later, regardless of whether or not I used method two with the standalone deriving and constraint, which again kind of makes sense. The `MonadIO` instance is *under the condition* of `MonadIO m`.

Is it only me, or is that counter-intuitive?

Does it have to do with the deprecated -XDatatypeContexts extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, all instances have the same constraint - the base type for `newtype` must be an instance of the same class:

[Generalised derived instances for newtypes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes)

> All the instance does is apply and remove the newtype constructor.

The derived instance for, i.e. `Monad` has the constraint `Monad (ExceptT e m)`, which already exists. However, there is no instance for `MonadIO (ExceptT e m)`, so it must be a constraint on the resulting `MonadIO` declaration.

If I try to *use* `MonadIO (Foo e m)`, an error is generated:

```
something :: Foo e m ()
something = liftIO $ print "5"
```

Here's the error:

```
    • No instance for (MonadIO m) arising from a use of ‘liftIO’
      Possible fix:
        add (MonadIO m) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            something :: Foo e m ()
    • In the expression: liftIO $ print "5"
      In an equation for ‘something’: something = liftIO $ print "5"
```

Comment: I am aware of that. But why is this done so awkwardly? E.g. when I derive `MonadError e`, I don't have to add any constraints later.

Comment: `MonadError e` doesn't require any constraints on `m` since the implementation from `ExceptT` is used, which works for all `m`. `MonadIO` cannot be implemented without a constraint on `m` since it must use an implementation from `m` and thus ensure that such an implementation exists. It isn't awkward, or it least it is precisely as awkward as it needs to be.

Comment: Added a link to the documentation and hopefully better explanation.